# Microsoft LightSwitch HTML5 Client Read QueryString?

Tags: visual-studio-lightswitch, lightswitch-2012

I am using LightSwitch HTML5 Client and have created the screen which contains new HTML5 table control .I also added the "Filter" popup in the "Browse Screen"  which queries against the Odata source and filters rows in the table.

There is a requirement in my project that user will click on "Url Link" for eg: [http://localhost:8958/HTMLClient/?WorkflowId=9289] which will redirect user to the ListSwitch HTML5 Client and the LightSwitch Application will read the QueryString "WorkFlowId" and will filter the records based on it.

Is it possible to read "QueryString" throught LightSwitch HTML5 Client and also to pre-process Odata query with that input

Answer (score 1, accepted):

LightSwitch client uses standard JavaScript or jQuery techniques to extract query string values.

Ex. : [How can I get query string values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/901115/how-can-i-get-query-string-values)

I see that you're familiar with PreProcessQuery. I'm guessing that you have trouble binding WorkflowId parameter to search request. If that's the case, I'd recommend checking out this video:

[How Do I: Filter Data on a Screen in the LightSwitch HTML Client?](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vstudio/dn195508)